# To Suppress Unwanted behaviour in JUnit4 with PowerMocking

Tags: junit4

how to suppress userComment in below line

```
UserComment userComment = (UserComment)hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(UserComment.class).add(Example.create(userCommentOld)).uniqueResult();
```

i mock every method in above line but when i debug gettting null in

```
  add(Example.create(userCommentOld))
```

so now i want to suppress the userComment

Is there any other method to suppress..?

Comment: could you please post only relevant code.

Comment: UserComment userComment = (UserComment)hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(UserComment.class).add(Example.create(userCommentOld)).uniqueResult(); i want to suppress userComment in this code i mock every method in the line but getting null when i mocked  when(criteria.add(Example.create(userCommentOld))).thenReturn(criteria); so i wanted to suppress userComment